# Redirect to other url if one word is coming in the url using htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi i need to create a soft 301 redirect if **"/myproject/"** is coming in my url i have to add **"blog/myproject/"** and redirect to that url

```
examlpe.com/myprojects/test.html => examlpe.com/blog/myprojects/test.html
examlpe.com/myprojects/myvilla.html => examlpe.com/blog/myprojects/myvilla.html
examlpe.com/myprojects/car.html => examlpe.com/blog/myprojects/car.html
```

there are lots of url coming like this .

How i can redirect ? I don't want to redirect one by one like this

```
Redirect 301 /examlpe.com/myprojects/test.html http://examlpe.com/blog/myprojects/test.html
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
Redirect 301 /myproject/ /blog/
```

This will redirect all requests from `/myproject/` to `/blog/`

Comment: thank you very much . But i want to redirect  /myproject/ to /blog/ /myproject/